# Return current best solution CPLEX Python API

Tags: python, cplex

Due to MIP problems which take long computation time, how do I instruct cplex to return current best solution when the computation time takes longer than, an hour for example, and the relative gap is at 5% for example?
Individually, I believe I can use both functions: `model.parameters.timelimit.set()` and `model.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap.set()`, but how do I combine both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a callback to enforce both conditions. The `mipex4.py` example that is shipped with CPLEX shows exactly how to do this.

Here is the callback from the example:

```
class TimeLimitCallback(MIPInfoCallback):

    def __call__(self):
        if not self.aborted and self.has_incumbent():
            gap = 100.0 * self.get_MIP_relative_gap()
            timeused = self.get_time() - self.starttime
            if timeused > self.timelimit and gap < self.acceptablegap:
                print("Good enough solution at", timeused, "sec., gap =",
                      gap, "%, quitting.")
                self.aborted = True
                self.abort()
```

And the relevant part of the rest:

```
c = cplex.Cplex(filename)

timelim_cb = c.register_callback(TimeLimitCallback)
timelim_cb.starttime = c.get_time()
timelim_cb.timelimit = 1
timelim_cb.acceptablegap = 10
timelim_cb.aborted = False

c.solve()

sol = c.solution

print()
# solution.get_status() returns an integer code
print("Solution status = ", sol.get_status(), ":", end=' ')
# the following line prints the corresponding string
print(sol.status[sol.get_status()])

if sol.is_primal_feasible():
    print("Solution value  = ", sol.get_objective_value())
else:
    print("No solution available.")
```

Comment: Hi, are the `timelim_cb.timelimit` and `timelim_cb.acceptablegap` in terms of seconds and percentage respectively? Thanks,

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For `timelimit` you can infer this from the documentation for [Callback.get_time()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.callbacks.Callback-class.html?view=kc#get_time). For `acceptablegap` you have to know that the gap is computed as with [CPXgetmiprelgap](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/getmiprelgap.html) in the Callable C Library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!